# Two SCR thyristor modules using gates tied together to trigger

Tags: triac, gate-driving, scr

When I tie the gates of a MCC 95-16 together, it conducts AC at decreasing gate milliamps as I raise input voltage. Is this acceptable to power a microwave transformer? My zero crossing opto driver at 150 mA seems to lack "oomph" and would use a relay to switch it on for maybe 100 milliseconds to spot weld battery tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet says the latching gate current is 150 mA. I assume this is per-gate not per-whole-module. Your driver probably cannot supply enough current to fully open and latch both of the thyristors at once.

Comment: i am latching one at a time thru the ac cycle, but exceding my driver wattage still, I believe. what I experimented with is pulling current from one scr's gate to latch the other scr each ac cycle. seems ok testing at 14 vac with a 2 amp resistance load . I want to feed a transformer 14 amps at 120v and will have a current peak at the start according to eli the ice man